# A Railway Timetable Application in Android

Tags: android

I wish to create an application in Android which can show the trains(details like train number, time, date, etc.) passing through a station, whose name will be clicked from a list by the user.

Please guide me with some pointers on how to implement this.

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this opensource project can help you [BETrains](http://code.google.com/p/betrains/). There are many [more](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=Android+train&projectsearch=Search+projects).

Answer (score 0):

- Sounds first to use a SQLite-Database structure for the trains and their timings. (Look for "android sqlite tutorial" in Google)
- Then use the Systemtime for the actual time and date (Calendar method)
- build methods to calculate starting and arriving times with actual times with using queries of your database